# Static function within class, how will memory be handled?

Tags: c++, function, memory, static, static-functions

I would like to use the following static function. This function will in turn compute the input, and std::cout a result. After the static function is called and taken off of the stack, will all of this memory associated with this class be freed? Is this equivalent to making an instance of this class within the scope of main, or would it only exist for the duration of this function call? Assume that the function is called as it is below in the main function. Also, further reading links would be great.

```
typedef std::vector< std::vector<int> > matrix;    
    class LCS
        {
            public:
                static void getLCS(std::string,std::string);
            private:
                void compute_alignment();
                std::vector<std::string> f1,f2;
                matrix cost,link;
        };
int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    //check command line args
    if(argc != 3){std::cout<<"usage: ./exe file1.txt file2.txt";exit(1);}
    //compute
    LCS::getLCS(argv[1],argv[2]);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Judging strictly from your question, all of the variables *declared inside of getLCS will die after the function is done if they are declared on the stack (no naked `new` of any kind)*. Nothing else should live beyond that. Calling the static function also does not create a new `LCS` class: static functions on classes behave almost exactly like free-functions, except they can have access modifiers placed on them for scoping within the class. [Static data and methods operate independently of their classes unless you explicitly use and intermingle them in member functions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2992948/static-class-data-members-and-constructors?rq=1).

EDIT:

Note that this is true of ALL C++ functions. Objects and primitives that are made on the stack will die/go-out-of-scope when that function / scope dies. As bonus fun, you can even create `scope` by slapping some braces `{ /* ... */ }` around some code arbitrarily! But it's usually not necessary to do stuff like that.

Good luck!

Comment: I see. So, if this function were to allocate memory on the stack for a private variable in LCS, it would be freed after the function goes out of scope. Say, if I used f1.resize(20) within getLCS.

Comment: @JordanDillonChapian Yep. All C++ objects clean themselves up when they go out of scope. If you make an `LCS` object in that function, it should clean itself up automatically, along with any vectors you allocate (these objects know how to clean themselves up when the objects go out of scope).

Comment: Note that the staticness of the getLCS function is irrelevant. The same rules for local variables apply even if getLCS were not static.